# How to set a variable to the output of a `docker-compose restart` command in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, docker-compose, stderr

I write a bash shell to detemine `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose restart`:

```
#!/bin/bash
re=$(docker-compose -f prod.yml restart)
echo re:${re}
if [[ -n ${re} && ${re} == *"No containers to restart"* ]];then
  echo -e '\e[0;31;1mNO CONTAINER FOUND. WILL EXEC UP COMMAND...\e[0m'
  docker-compose -f prod.yml up
fi
```

but each time I exec this script, the var `re` is always empty. The output of script is:

```
ERROR: No containers to restart
re:
```

- `ERROR: No containers to restart` is the output of `docker-compose -f prod.yml restart`

Is there any way to solve this issue or another way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: Add output of `docker-compose -f prod.yml restart` to your question.

Comment: Checking for a particular output string is brittle and error-prone. If Docker is at all correctly written, it will set its exit code to reflect whether it succeeded. Then you can simply say `if docker-compose -f prod.yml restart; then`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to redirect stderr output.
For example:
 `re=$(docker-compose -f prod.yml restart 2>&1)`